# Find the corners of a polygon represented by a region mask

Tags: matlab, geometry, computer-vision, polygon, corner-detection

> `BW = poly2mask(x, y, m, n)` computes a
>   binary region of interest (ROI) mask,
>   BW, from an ROI polygon, represented
>   by the vectors x and y. The size of BW
>   is m-by-n.
>
> `poly2mask` sets pixels in BW
>   that are inside the polygon (X,Y) to 1
>   and sets pixels outside the polygon to
>   0.

**Problem:**
Given such a binary mask `BW` of a convex quadrilateral, what would be the most efficient way to determine the four corners?

E.g.,

[image: Example]

**Best Solution so far:**
Use `edge` to find the bounding lines, the Hough transform to find the 4 lines in the edge image and then find the intersection points of those 4 lines or use a corner detector on the edge image. Seems complicated, and I can't help feeling there's a simpler solution out there.

Btw, `convhull` doesn't always return 4 points (maybe someone can suggest `qhull` options to prevent that) : it returns a few points along the edges as well.

**EDIT:**
[Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711916/find-the-corners-of-a-polygon-represented-by-a-region-mask/1713400#1713400) seems quite elegant and efficient. But there could be multiple "corners" at each real corner since the peaks aren't unique. I could cluster them based on **θ** and average the "corners" around a real corner but the main problem is the use of `order(1:10)`.

Is `10` enough to account for all the corners or will this exclude a "corner" at a real corner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to what [@AndyL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712945/97160) suggested. However I'm using the boundary signature in polar coordinates instead of the tangent.

Note that I start by extracting the edges, getting the boundary, then converting it to signature.  Finally we find the points on the boundary that are furthest from the centroid, those points constitute the corners found. (Alternatively we can also detect peaks in the signature for corners).

The following is a complete implementation:

```
I = imread('oxyjj.png');
if ndims(I)==3
    I = rgb2gray(I);
end
subplot(221), imshow(I), title('org')

%%# Process Image
%# edge detection
BW = edge(I, 'sobel');
subplot(222), imshow(BW), title('edge')

%# dilation-erosion
se = strel('disk', 2);
BW = imdilate(BW,se);
BW = imerode(BW,se);
subplot(223), imshow(BW), title('dilation-erosion')

%# fill holes
BW = imfill(BW, 'holes');
subplot(224), imshow(BW), title('fill')

%# get boundary
B = bwboundaries(BW, 8, 'noholes');
B = B{1};

%%# boudary signature
%# convert boundary from cartesian to ploar coordinates
objB = bsxfun(@minus, B, mean(B));
[theta, rho] = cart2pol(objB(:,2), objB(:,1));

%# find corners
%#corners = find( diff(diff(rho)>0) < 0 );     %# find peaks
[~,order] = sort(rho, 'descend');
corners = order(1:10);

%# plot boundary signature + corners
figure, plot(theta, rho, '.'), hold on
plot(theta(corners), rho(corners), 'ro'), hold off
xlim([-pi pi]), title('Boundary Signature'), xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho')

%# plot image + corners
figure, imshow(BW), hold on
plot(B(corners,2), B(corners,1), 's', 'MarkerSize',10, 'MarkerFaceColor','r')
hold off, title('Corners')
```

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

---

**EDIT:**
In response to Jacob's comment, I should explain that I first tried to find the peaks in the signature using first/second derivatives, but ended up taking the furthest N-points. 10 was just an ad-hoc value, and would be difficult to generalize (I tried taking 4 same as number of corners, but it didn't cover all of them). I think the idea of clustering them to remove duplicates is worth looking into.

As far as I see it, the problem with the 1st approach was that if you plot `rho` without taking `θ` into account, you will get a different shape (not the same peaks), since the *speed* by which we trace the boundary is different and depends on the curvature. If we could figure out how to *normalize* that effect, we can get more accurate results using derivatives.

Comment: I just realized that you already have a binary image BW. Therefore you can skip directly to the part of getting the boundaries starting with the call to **bwboundaries**

Comment: +1 - for the boundary signature. But, there are some concerns which I've detailed in the edited post.

Comment: @Amro: Thanks a lot for the boundary signature idea, but I decided to dig up my old implementation of the Harris corner detector and use it.

Comment: U could should some line approximation technique to solve the corner duplication issue. OpenCV does that in findContours function using the CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE flag. As for matlab, I didn't find a built-in way to do it, but found an implementation of Douglas-Peucker simplification algorithm on file exchange http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21132-line-simplification

Comment: OpenCV approxPolyDP also implements Douglas-Peucker algorithm http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cvapproxpoly#approxpolydp

Comment: @OSaad: thank you for the reference. Actually not long ago there was a similar problem on [Steve](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2012/07/09/a-cody-problem-simplify-a-polygon/) [Eddins](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2012/07/25/cody-problem-solvers-simplify-a-polygon/) [blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2012/08/28/wrapping-up-the-analysis-of-cody-solutions/) which was turned into a [Cody challenge](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/820/), about how to simplify the output of `bwboundaries` in case of polygons.. I think the line simplification technique was mentioned:)

Answer (score 8):

If you have the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/), there is a function called [`cornermetric`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cornermetric.html) which can implement a Harris corner detector or Shi and Tomasi's minimum eigenvalue method. This function has been present since version 6.2 of the Image Processing Toolbox (MATLAB version R2008b).

Using this function, I came up with a slightly different approach from the other answers. The solution below is based on the idea that a circular area centered at each "true" corner point will overlap the polygon by a smaller amount than a circular area centered over an erroneous corner point that is actually on the edge. This solution can also handle cases where multiple points are detected at the same corner...

The first step is to load the data:

```
rawImage = imread('oxyjj.png');
rawImage = rgb2gray(rawImage(7:473, 9:688, :));  % Remove the gray border
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(rawImage);
title('Raw image');
```

Next, compute the corner metric using [`cornermetric`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cornermetric.html). Note that I am masking the corner metric by the original polygon, so that we are looking for corner points that are *inside* the polygon (i.e. trying to find the corner pixels of the polygon). [`imregionalmax`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html) is then used to find the local maxima. Since you can have clusters of greater than 1 pixel with the same corner metric, I then add noise to the maxima and recompute so that I only get 1 pixel in each maximal region. Each maximal region is then labeled using [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html):

```
cornerImage = cornermetric(rawImage).*(rawImage > 0);
maxImage = imregionalmax(cornerImage);
noise = rand(nnz(maxImage), 1);
cornerImage(maxImage) = cornerImage(maxImage)+noise;
maxImage = imregionalmax(cornerImage);
labeledImage = bwlabel(maxImage);
```

The labeled regions are then dilated (using [`imdilate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html)) with a disk-shaped structuring element (created using [`strel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel-class.html)):

```
diskSize = 5;
dilatedImage = imdilate(labeledImage, strel('disk', diskSize));
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow(dilatedImage);
title('Dilated corner points');
```

Now that the labeled corner regions have been dilated, they will partially overlap the original polygon. Regions on an edge of the polygon will have about 50% overlap, while regions that are on a corner will have about 25% overlap. The function [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) can be used to find the areas of overlap for each labeled region, and the 4 regions that have the least amount of overlap can thus be considered as the true corners:

```
maskImage = dilatedImage.*(rawImage > 0);       % Overlap with the polygon
stats = regionprops(maskImage, 'Area');         % Compute the areas
[sortedValues, index] = sort([stats.Area]);     % Sort in ascending order
cornerLabels = index(1:4);                      % The 4 smallest region labels
maskImage = ismember(maskImage, cornerLabels);  % Mask of the 4 smallest regions
subplot(2, 2, 3);
imshow(maskImage);
title('Regions of minimal overlap');
```

And we can now get the pixel coordinates of the corners using [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
[r, c] = find(ismember(labeledImage, cornerLabels));
subplot(2, 2, 4);
imshow(rawImage);
hold on;
plot(c, r, 'r+', 'MarkerSize', 16, 'LineWidth', 2);
title('Corner points');
```

[image]

And here's a test with a diamond shaped region:

[image]

Comment: +1 I didn't know this one. Looking at its implementation, its similar to @Jacob's though more optimized.

Comment: I'm using R2009a, so I guess it's a relatively new addition.

Answer (score 4):

I like to solve this problem by working with a boundary, because it reduces this from a 2D problem to a 1D problem.

Use `bwtraceboundary()` from the image processing toolkit to extract a list of points on the boundary. Then convert the boundary into a series of tangent vectors (there are a number of ways to do this, one way would be to subrtact the 
`i`th point along the boundary from the `i+delta`th point.) Once you have a list of vectors, take the dot product of adjacent vectors. The four points with the smallest dot products are your corners!

If you want your algorithm to work on polygons with an abritrary number of vertices, then simply search for dot products that are a certain number of standard deviations below the median dot product.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to use a [Harris corner detector](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rcollins/CSE486/lecture06_6pp.pdf) (here's a [more formal description](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~kosta/CompVis_Notes/harris_detector.pdf)) to obtain the corners. This can be implemented as follows:

```
%% Constants
Window = 3;
Sigma = 2;
K = 0.05;
nCorners = 4;

%% Derivative masks
dx = [-1 0 1; -1 0 1; -1 0 1];
dy = dx';   %SO code color fix '

%% Find the image gradient
% Mask is the binary image of the quadrilateral
Ix = conv2(double(Mask),dx,'same');   
Iy = conv2(double(Mask),dy,'same');

%% Use a gaussian windowing function and compute the rest
Gaussian = fspecial('gaussian',Window,Sigma);
Ix2 = conv2(Ix.^2,  Gaussian, 'same');  
Iy2 = conv2(Iy.^2,  Gaussian, 'same');
Ixy = conv2(Ix.*Iy, Gaussian, 'same');    

%% Find the corners
CornerStrength = (Ix2.*Iy2 - Ixy.^2) - K*(Ix2 + Iy2).^2;
[val ind] = sort(CornerStrength(:),'descend');    
[Ci Cj] = ind2sub(size(CornerStrength),ind(1:nCorners));

%% Display
imshow(Mask,[]);
hold on;
plot(Cj,Ci,'r*');
```

Here, the problem with multiple corners thanks to Gaussian windowing function which smooths the intensity change. Below, is a zoomed version of a corner with the `hot` colormap.

[image: corner]

Comment: nice! as a note, I like to put `#` after `%` in MATLAB comments, so that it gets correct SO color

Comment: Thanks! Any fixes with using `'`?

Comment: Nope. Listen I was testing your approach, and it seems it's not perfect either (which is always the case in Computer Vision!). Try the following mask with your code above: `x = [16 282 276 30 16]; y = [14 29 200 225 14]; BW = poly2mask(x,y, 246,300);` you will get some duplicate corners (even when tried tuning the other params), and will have to increase `nCorners` too..

Comment: You're completely right - looks like clustering is required for some polygons.

Comment: I don't want to push my idea too strongly, but I think that the signature method could be perfected for most quadrilateral if we locate the exact 4 *theta peaks*, which are after all clearly visible in the plot. Picking the highest N-points may not have been the best way, but maybe someone can improve that part..

Comment: I found a way to account for multiple points at corners by adding some noise to the maximal corner metric values (I've updated my answer to include it). I was also able to ensure that my implementation would always pick a corner point from the pixels *within* the polygon by masking the corner metrics with the original polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using Ruby and [HornetsEye](http://www.wedesoft.demon.co.uk/hornetseye-api/). Basically the program creates a histogram of the quantised Sobel gradient orientation to find dominant orientations. If four dominant orientations are found, lines are fitted and the intersections between neighbouring lines are assumed to be the corners of the projected rectangle.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'hornetseye'
include Hornetseye
Q = 36
img = MultiArray.load_ubyte 'http://imgur.com/oxyjj.png'
dx, dy = 8, 6
box = [ dx ... 688, dy ... 473 ]
crop = img[ *box ]
crop.show
s0, s1 = crop.sobel( 0 ), crop.sobel( 1 )
mag = Math.sqrt s0 ** 2 + s1 ** 2
mag.normalise.show
arg = Math.atan2 s1, s0
msk = mag >= 500
arg_q = ( ( arg.mask( msk ) / Math::PI + 1 ) * Q / 2 ).to_int % Q
hist = arg_q.hist_weighted Q, mag.mask( msk )
segments = ( hist >= hist.max / 4 ).components
lines = arg_q.map segments
lines.unmask( msk ).normalise.show
if segments.max == 4
  pos = MultiArray.scomplex *crop.shape
  pos.real = MultiArray.int( *crop.shape ).indgen! % crop.shape[0]
  pos.imag = MultiArray.int( *crop.shape ).indgen! / crop.shape[0]
  weights = lines.hist( 5 ).major 1.0
  centre = lines.hist_weighted( 5, pos.mask( msk ) ) / weights
  vector = pos.mask( msk ) - lines.map( centre )
  orientation = lines.hist_weighted( 5, vector ** 2 ) ** 0.5
  corner = Sequence[ *( 0 ... 4 ).collect do |i|
    i1, i2 = i + 1, ( i + 1 ) % 4 + 1
    l1, a1, l2, a2 = centre[i1], orientation[i1], centre[i2], orientation[i2]
    ( l1 * a1.conj * a2 - l2 * a1 * a2.conj -
      l1.conj * a1 * a2 + l2.conj * a1 * a2 ) /
      ( a1.conj * a2 - a1 * a2.conj )
  end ] 
  result = MultiArray.ubytergb( *img.shape ).fill! 128
  result[ *box ] = crop
  corner.to_a.each do |c|
    result[ c.real.to_i + dx - 1 .. c.real.to_i + dx + 1,
            c.imag.to_i + dy - 1 .. c.imag.to_i + dy + 1 ] = RGB 255, 0, 0
  end
  result.show
end
```

[image: Image with estimated position of corners]