# Detect Corners of Triangle in Image on iPhone

Tags: iphone, opencv, imagemagick

Hey guys,
I'm having a slight problem when finalizing my app; indeed, up until now, at some point, the user had to select the three vertices of a triangle with some draggable objects. Now, even though this isn't a problem, I thought it could be interesting to have close to zero user-interaction, and have my app pick out the vertices of the triangle in an image, and automatically place the markers on the correct spots.

After doing some research, and thinking about stuff lile OpenCV, ImageMagick, etc, I'm not really certain as to how one would recognize and find the location of the vertices of a triangle in an image. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: If someone has a solution that doesn't involve amy external libraries, I'd still be quite glad to hear it!

Comment: `Vertex` (plural `vertices`) is the correct term, although "corner" is used for triangles quite commonly anyway.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. Do you have any idea on how to detect the location of these vertices?

Comment: Do you have a link to what the image of the triangle might look like? Perhaps a harris corner detector?

Comment: The image of the triangle would be quite simple, just a (right) triangle on a plain background. Would a corner detector give me the coordinates of the corners?

Comment: Here is a sample image: http://teasleyes.typepad.com/.a/6a00d834524ed969e20120a7367788970b-800wi

Comment: I saw that OpenCV has several corner extraction methods; does this example piece of code look like what I need? http://fahmifahim.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/opencv-corner-detection/

Comment: @Elton: your sample image is sufficiently simple that you could very easily generate such an image programmatically, using the core 2D methods. Then, you wouldn't need to do any feature detection, because you'd know that the vertices are wherever you chose to draw them.

Comment: That is very true, but the image is selected by the user, either through his library or the camera.

Comment: Btw, I imagine that a Harris Corner Detection algorithm occasionally has faulty results: is there any way to set the 'strength' of the vertices being looked for?

Comment: @Elton: the Harris corner detector's output is in the form of an image with the corners as the local maxima. So you'll have to run a maxima finding routine on the output image of the harris function

Comment: alternatively since your images are standard ones, use the probabilistic Hough LIne transform to detect straight lines. Consider the first 5/6 prominent ones (you can set the sensitivity). The output is in two CvPoints of the lines from which you can find the intersection of the lines and get the vertices.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info regarding the Hough transform, it seemed like too much of a hassle deciding which corners were real lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to detect shapes in images and then detect the corners of those shapes using a variety of different image processing techniques. See for example this [SO question about detecting corners of polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711916/find-the-corners-of-a-polygon-represented-by-a-region-mask/1712945#1712945) and [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711916/find-the-corners-of-a-polygon-represented-by-a-region-mask/1712945#1712945).

Whether this will actually be a simple or difficult task depends greatly on how much information you can safely assume about the image of your triangle.

For example, if your images are computer generated and have only a triangle in them and nothing else and if the triangle contrasts sharply with the  background, as below, than you could write something in a few lines of code using OpenCV that would find your vertices.
 [image: triangle from wikipedia]

In that case, you would convert your image to a grayscale image,  apply a threshold to  to create a binary image, use a built in function find the boundary of the image, and then use any of the methods in the SO question to find the corners.

If on the other hand you are dealing with a photograph of a triangle, your problem becomes much more difficult, because it will not be as simple to acquire a binary image of your triangle. You will have to deal with unknown lighting and background conditions. You may not be able to use a simple threshold, and you won't know what value threshold to use. You will likely need to do some kind of edge detection on your image, and you will be looking at a time consuming project. For a start, see the O'Reilly book, [Learning OpenCV](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130).

[image]

Comment: Great answer, and thanks to everyone for their time and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Feature-detection is complicated stuff, so unless you want to write your own from scratch, you're stuck with using a third-party library.  Here's one that looks promising:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

Comment: I've taken a look at that library; what in particular should I be using from it though?