# find position of image surranded by black area

Tags: matlab

There is an image, surrounded by black region, I would like to find the exact locaton of this image (which is surrounded by black region). I mean the coordinates of four corners of this image. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the corners of a polygon represented by a region mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711916/find-the-corners-of-a-polygon-represented-by-a-region-mask)

Comment: but question is not about binary image...

Comment: @chee: But you can *create* a binary image (i.e. everything not in the surrounding black region) and apply the solution in the linked question.

Comment: Please specify your input and output more clearly. Is the image a bitmap? Do you want the pixel coordinates of the corners?

Comment: its a jpg image , and yes wants to get pixel coordinates of corners to get the location of image.

Comment: @chee: Did you find your answer?

Comment: Ditto what 2astalavista said, slash did you look at my answer?? :P

Comment: @2astalavista yes i got the ans... thankyou so much and tylerthemiler thanx for answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in matlab:

Mask out the black area. Either try:

```
Image = logical(Image)
```

Or find the intensity of a black voxel (probably zero) and say:

```
Image = ind2sub(size(Image), find(Image ~= blackPixelIntensity))
```

Once you have the binary non-black part of the image (so just the object and not the background), you just want to find the min, max corners of each voxel. Say:

```
[x y] = ind2sub(size(Image), find(Image ~= 0))
c1 = [min(x) min(y)]
c2 = [max(x) min(y)]
c3 = [max(x) max(y)]
c4 = [min(x) min(y)]
```

Where c1,...,c4 are your corners :)

Lemme know about any syntax error as I don't have access to matlab atm.

tylerthemiler

Edit: if you simply want the entire perimeter of the non-black part of the image, just do whichever of the first two lines of code above works, and then say:

```
Imperim = bwperim(Image)
```

Edit2: Note that Image is the 2D array, you can use whatever you want to load in the jpg :P

Comment: Heh, "black voxel" too used to 3D :P

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a second derivative mask on your image which will then accurately pick up the points at which the colour goes from black to the content of the picture. You can then extract the first and last row and column each and you've got your coordinates.